# max element in specific structure

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sum, max

I have array of length n, from which I build such sequence b that:

```
b[0] = 0
b[1] = b[0] + a[0]
b[2] = b[1] + a[0]
b[3] = b[2] + a[1]
b[4] = b[3] + a[0]
b[5] = b[4] + a[1]
b[6] = b[5] + a[2]
b[7] = b[6] + a[0]
b[8] = b[7] + a[1]
b[9] = b[8] + a[2]
b[10] = b[9] + a[3]
#etc.
```

a can contain non-positive values. I need to find max element of b. I only came up with O(n^2) solution. Is there faster approach?

```
def find_max(a):
  b = [0]
  i = 0
  count = 0
  while i < len(a):
    j = 0
    while j <= i:
      b.append(b[count] + a[j])
      count += 1
      j += 1
    i += 1
  return max(b)
```

Comment: I do see O(n) but I'm not in the mood to write testing code... Might be good if you could add some that we can use, with realistic n and values.

Comment: I don't think an O(n) solution is possible unless you are able to somehow generate `b` in `O(1)` time

Comment: @smac89 You don't need to generate `b`.

Comment: @smac89 Wrote/posted mine after all now... Yet again proves that calling something impossible is a big motivator :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**O(n) time and O(1) space.**

Consider this (outer loop) round:

```
b[4] = b[3] + a[0]   = b[3] + a[0]
b[5] = b[4] + a[1]   = b[3] + a[0] + a[1]
b[6] = b[5] + a[2]   = b[3] + a[0] + a[1] + a[2]
```

You don't need all of these. It's enough to know:

- The maximum of them. Which is `b[3] + max(prefix sums of a[:3])`.
- The last of them, `b[6] = b[3] + sum(a[:3])`. Because you need that for the next round.

In general, to find the maximum of each round, it's enough to know:

- The `b` value which the round starts with.
- The max prefix sum of `a[:...]`.

Add them together to know the max `b`-value in the round. And return the maximum of these rounds maximums.

We can update these values in O(1) time for each round:

```
def find_max_linear(a):
  b = max_b = 0 
  sum_a = max_sum_a = 0
  for x in a:
    sum_a += x
    max_sum_a = max(max_sum_a, sum_a)
    max_b = max(max_b, b + max_sum_a)
    b += sum_a
  return max_b
```

Testing:

```
import random
for _ in range(10):
  a = random.choices(range(-100, 101), k=100)
  expect = find_max(a)
  result = find_max_linear(a)
  print(result == expect, expect, result)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVFBboQwDFSvvMJHEOwq3KpqeQlCKIFQQiGJQtDSt_Syl_YLfUv7miYkQHqyxzOxx87Hl3zXveCPn--WdtAx3tYTXmOcvEQABAooUWUyZjJkYiMWrn1-79lIDXODkXL_AmDw7M4PcCuAOc50vGIpKW9jUm6tKkgBl0OVeN71TwvIfWE4AdtTRfWiOFifJPlcdHd5_n26h_7rkXGKVbCGLdqIwBTmZaqxL-659dwJBSswDtj5dZyZum4wlNvhB86cMjlUJFCQzBhIz8dORWzbDf9bqCZRxCYplAaFeSumyHqqrSeDX2mco20la8EJrk0vWEPn2PGXHKEMcpQnGbwVBthxdJW0sd8W_O82dl7GsHyezbBSMa7jXVP4JtkRHePv__DBxz8)):

```
True 8277 8277
True 2285 2285
True 5061 5061
True 19261 19261
True 0 0
True 0 0
True 47045 47045
True 531 531
True 703 703
True 24073 24073
```

Fun oneliner (also O(n) time, but O(n) space due to the unpacking):

```py
from itertools import accumulate as acc
from operator import add

def find_max_linear(a):
  return max(0, *map(add, acc(acc(a), initial=0), acc(acc(a), max)))
```

Or broken into a few lines with comments:

```
def find_max_linear(a):
  return max(0, *map(
    add,
    acc(acc(a), initial=0),  # each round's initial b-value
    acc(acc(a), max)         # each round's max prefix sum of a[:...]
  ))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVHLbcMwDEWvmoJHqXEC-VYU8QwZwAgCxaYbubIkyDKaztJLLu0KnaWdprStJO5B4OeR75HUx5d_jydnLz_fNTbQaFsfOnXmSjwzgCMUUMo9eZo8SbZyg43Jfztpg4RswaBNHQBtQq94C9sC9IwR40Z5j7bmx3Ki2sMKVNnuRcJn_lUBeUq090Bf3YBxCBbGOY_ic4jN-un3YdcE14GOGKJzpgfdeRciqKoausGoiKD6MWJTnfMYVHThVlbXjC0vcDDaogpprYWizOCxU55TRzby8emJDLTVUStTSPE_T01CCMZYkgrK1q5jDYkfqGmMX5DnchJSdL25YFOdnK6w5zO-ziUp5zInxteCgvFiePZYjd-x-Ldp2n4wy_R9GUJ90Dbya02RSLKbnZF010syyf4B)

Comment: A very much tidier implementation of my brain fart first-thought. Very elegant. Nice!  *(I had to mentally rename `b` to `sum_sum_a` to understand that it's right though)*

Comment: @MatBailie Yeah, when I originally thought of it I thought it could get messy, and then I was pleasantly surprised how tidy it ended up. I even like my variable names :-)

Comment: @MatBailie We can probably make that a "oneliner" with itertools. I might try that later if nobody beats me to it...

Comment: I'd probably reject that merge request as being significantly less maintainable without sufficient benefit.

Comment: @MatBailie I'm such a sucker, did it already. How do you like it?

Comment: Clever, but I'd still reject it unless optimising a critical loop (I can only half understand it from reading it, I'd have to play with it to get my head around it, and I profoundly dislike code like that in my code bases)

Comment: @MatBailie Agreed. I find it intriguing, and readable if you already know my original (at least the multiline version, now with comments), but I prefer the original as well.

Comment: Now I've had a sleep and read the multiline commented version, I'm more aware of the elegance :) Does unpacking (`*map()`) "materialise" all the elements, and make this O(n) in space? Would `itertools.chain` be an alternative?

Comment: @MatBailie Heh, yeah, together with my extended explanation and the corresponding new comments, I almost prefer the multiline oneliner now. Yes, the unpacking makes it take O(n) space and yes, `chain` would be one way to make it O(1). I had actually used it in an earlier version but removed it for brevity. I'll mention the O(n) to avoid misleading.

Answer (score 4):

Untested, but `O(n)`.

```
def find_max (a):
    # This will be the total sum to this point.
    cumulative = []
    # This will be the local best of the cumulative values to this point.
    local_best = []

    # The empty sum is 0.
    best = current = 0
    for value in a:
        current += value
        cumulative.append(current)
        best = max(current, best)
        local_best.append(best)

    # Reset before doing our big cumulative sum.
    best = current = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        # The best we can partway through adding a[0]+a[1]+...+a[i]
        best = max(best, current + local_best[i])
        # The result after adding a[0]+a[1]+...+a[i]
        current += cumulative[i]

    return best
```

Comment: Untested, but definitely on the right track. I finally see what was eluding me is that you can precompute some of the values

Answer (score 0):

Still quadratic, but seems about five times faster and I find it clearer/nicer<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
from itertools import chain, accumulate

def find_max_2(a):
    def prefixes():
        prefix = []
        for x in a:
            prefix.append(x)
            yield prefix
    increments = chain.from_iterable(prefixes())
    return max(accumulate(increments, initial=0))
```

One-liner for fun, seems still four times faster than yours:

```
from itertools import chain, islice, repeat, accumulate

def find_max_fun(a):
    return max(accumulate(chain(*map(islice, repeat(a), range(1, len(a) + 1))), initial=0))
```

Or with a [helper tool](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/):

```
def Shlemiel(xs):
    path = []
    for x in xs:
        path.append(x)
        yield from path

def find_max_fun(a):
    return max(accumulate(Shlemiel(a), initial=0))
```

---

[1] Although that might just be because you used rather unpythonic code. I might write yours like this:

```
def find_max(a):
    b = [0]
    for i in range(1, len(a) + 1):
        for x in a[:i]:
            b.append(b[-1] + x)
    return max(b)
```